# Django url mapping for similar patterns

Tags: django

My `dir` structure is as follows:

```
mainFolder
--myProject
---urls.py
--mysite
---urls.py
```

In myProject folder's urls.py I have:

```
   url(r'^$', 'mysite.views.home', name='home'),
```

I changed it to

```
url(r'^$', include(mysite.urls)),
```

I would like my application to use `mysite.urls.py` for all requests, e.g.

```
localhost:8000/ OR
localhost:8000/abc OR
localhost:8000/def 
etcetera
```

How do I configure the url parameters in `myProject.urls.py` in order to do this?

Comment: Try not specifying any expression to match `url(r'', include(mysite.urls)), `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

url(r'', include(mysite.urls)),

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the '$' from the url pattern.

---

You can use the following syntax
`url(r'^', include(mysite.urls))`

More info on why "^$" is used can be found [here](http://satishgandham.com/2013/06/what-do-dollar-and-caret-and-sign-in-django-urls-mean/)